# Why is zero times vector of reals not zero?

Tags: assumptions

Using the following global assumptions

`$Assumptions = Element[n, Integers] && Element[a, Vectors[n, Reals]] && b == 0 && Element[c, Reals]`

I assumed that
`Refine[a.b]`

returns 0. Instead, it returns `[a.0]`, which again according to my knowledge should be a vector of n zeros.

`Refine[b*c]`

works as expected and returns zero.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've used the dot product operator (.) instead of the times operator (*). In some languages like Matlab, * is the dot operator, but in Mathematica they are different.

```
{1,2,3} * 0 == {0,0,0}
{1,2,3} * {0,0,0} == {0,0,0}
{1,2,3} . {0,0,0} == 0
```

Since you are refining a vector dotted with 0, Mathematica doesn't know how to simplify this, so it simply returns the expression a.0.

Curiously,

```
Refine[a*0, Assumptions -> Element[a, Vectors[n, Reals]]]
```

and

```
Refine[a*b, Assumptions -> {Element[a, Vectors[n, Reals]], b==0}]
```

both yield 0 as well, even if `n` is replaced by a number like 10; I suspect that this is due to a shortcut *Mathematica* takes in seeing a*0 passed to `Refine`, but I'm not sure why this particular instance yields 0.

Comment: `TensorExpand[Refine[a.b]]`